# terminal in visual studio code freezes and does not let you write

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, git-bash, freeze

i need help, every time i try to use the integrated terminal in visual studio code it freezes and won't let me write anything. powershell throws a code error "2" and the gitbash terminal just won't let me write.  I have already tried uninstalling the terminals and it doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I've found a temporary work-around to it. If I exit Windows maximize mode of VS Code's window, the terminal will get active again.
Basically you just double-click the top part of the window or click the upper-right maximize icon.

However, I would like to solve this problem permanently and the first thing to look at are the active extensions to see if one of them is causing the issue. Maybe you could share your list of extensions and we can see if there's a match?

Here's mine:

```
File Watcher
Dart
Flutter
ESLint
Make Hidden
GitLens — Git supercharged
GitHub Copilot
Dart Data Class Generator
SVG
IntelliJ IDEA Keybindings
Flutter Intl
Subtitles Editor
Prisma
Thunder Client
Night Owl
```